# Compare true/false array with other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

What is the quickest way to compare two arrays and return a third array containing the values from `array2` where the associated values from `array1` are `true`?

```
const array1 = [true, false, false, true];
const array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

The result should be:

```
const result = ['a', 'd'];
```

Comment: are you asking for the quickest way as in performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `filter`.

```js
const array1 = [true, false, false, true];
const array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const res = array2.filter((_, i) => array1[i]);
console.log(res);
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var array1 = [true, false, false, true];
var array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var res = array2.filter(function(_, i) {
  return array1[i];
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Filter` function is slower than for loop. The quicker option is to use for loop **with** or **without** ternary operator.. It is faster than the `filter` function.

I've include a code snippet that shows how long each option takes.

```js
const array1 = [true, false, false, true];
const array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

// filter
console.time('filter');
const result1 = array2.filter((_, i) => array1[i]);
console.timeEnd('filter');
console.log(result1);

// for loop with ternary operator
console.time('forLoopWithTernary');
const result2 = [];
for(let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
  (array1[i]) ? result2.push(array2[i]) : null;
}
console.timeEnd('forLoopWithTernary');
console.log(result2);

// for loop w/o ternary operator
console.time('forLoopWithoutTernary');
const result3 = [];
for(let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
  if(array1[i])
    result3.push(array2[i]);
}
console.timeEnd('forLoopWithoutTernary');
console.log(result3);
```

Comment: I get 0ms for all of them, and I greatly prefer the readability of `.filter`…

Comment: @deceze I prefer the readability of `filter` as well; however, the OP did ask for the quickest way. On my end, I get 0.060ms for `filter`, 0.010ms for `forLoopWithTernary`, and 0.010ms for `forLoopWithoutTernary`. The time do change on each run.. Not much of difference I admit, but it is as OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var array1 = [true, false, false, true];
var array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

console.time('reduce');
var res = array1.reduce((total, currentValue, index) => {
    return currentValue ? [...total, array2[index]] : total;
  },  []);
console.log(res);
console.timeEnd('reduce');
```